# Why can not I have 2 loops in the same method on an equal list? JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, list, concurrency, exception

I'm studying for java 8 certification, and I discovered an incredible thing!

I'm attending a course, during explanation about List in Java he talk about **ConcurrentModificationException**.

Look at this fragment:

```
List<String> lista = new LinkedList<>();

lista.add("d");
lista.add("d");
lista.add("d");
lista.add("d");

for(int i = 0; i<lista.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(lista.get(i));

}

for(String s : lista){
    lista.add(s);
}}
```

Why java without **ITERATOR** throw **ConcurrentModificationException**?

Should not the list be read from the first cycle, and only once it has finished with the first one start with the second?

How can the second loop be executed while the first is still iterating?

Comment: It's not the two loops that's the problem - it's the fact that the second loop is **modifying the list it is iterating over**.

Comment: *How can the second loop be executed while the first is still iterating?* what is the use case behind this question ?

Comment: you cannot modify a list while looping through that list.

Comment: for(String s : lista) internally use iterator. and you are access and inserting at same time that it is throwing ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: The 2nd loop itself is the problem. Even if you remove the first loop from your code you will still get ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: Think about it, if you wouldn't get an exception you would end up with an infinite loop because you are adding to your list whatever is in your list and your list keeps in growing.

Comment: LOL thank you @isaace ! now all is clear!!!!!! 

I thought the problem was the combination of two loop in cascade! ndr

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: When you assume that the problem is connected to both loops, it should take less than a minute to disprove yourself by just running the code two times with either loop without the other. Isolating the problem by testing before drawing any conclusions should become your standard procedure. Besides that, I’ll recommend reading [“When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2711488)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with second is you are adding new elements. However in the first you just reading.

Imagine the case, you keep counting books and someone inserting book in middle. How irritating ? Without inserting new books, no matter how many times you read it, the result won't change.

Answer (score 2):

The `for (Element e: list)` construct internally uses an `Iterator<Element>`, which explains your `ConcurrentModificationException`.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) for instance:

> The compiler does [create the `Iterator`] for you behind your back, but you need not concern yourself with it.*

--> you actually do need to concern yourself with it, if you intend to modify the stucture while iterating over it.

*Content between square brackets replaced by me for clarity.

Comment: The question was different. Immagine this scenario:

System.out.println("Ciao"); // LINE 1

System.out.println("HI"); // LINE 2

The line 2 can't be executed if JVM dont execute before the line 1.

So why i shoud worry about the second loop, if it will be executed after the read of  list?

Comment: And btw if i use an iterator like this :

 for( Iterator iterator = lista.iterator(); iterator.hasNext()){
        lista.add(s);
    }}

The code will run fine

Comment: Of course changing the second loop to use an iterator works although you're adding each element again which seems...odd.
Have you actually understood any of these answers?